# Crear una subconsulta usando dato JSON MariaDB

Tags: json, mariadb

Estoy iniciando a trabajar con datos JSON y en una subquery no logro obtener los datos según el JSON que tengo en la columna idHostGroup, me están mostrando todos los registos haciendo caso omiso al valor JSON.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mi Tabla customernews es

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Intenté aplicar diversas funciones de MariaDB pero no logré obtener el resultado esperado, pero esta función json_table estoy entendiendo que debería ayudarme a solucionar mi problema.

Estoy necesitando que cada fila de mi tabla customernews relacione a mi tabla hostgroups concatenando los resultados según el ID de cada fila JSON guardado en la columna idHostGroup

Comment: ¿Puede publicar las estructuras de las tablas (en texto no imagen) y el resultado esperado de la consulta?.